# No index used for $or query

Tags: mongodb

I try to run the following query which does not seem to pick up the index

```
{$or: [{"sub_transactions.address_from": "df1qqal78l5uj8j86pq5ckchctgwxtn7uus5g53f8q"}, {"sub_transactions.address_to": "df1qqal78l5uj8j86pq5ckchctgwxtn7uus5g53f8q"}]}
```

explain shows the following

```
{
 "stage": "COLLSCAN",
 "planNodeId": 1,
 "nReturned": 41,
 "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 465,
 "opens": 1,
 "closes": 1,
 "saveState": 584,
 "restoreState": 584,
 "isEOF": 1,
 "numTested": 584877,
 "filter": {
  "$or": [
   {
    "sub_transactions.address_from": {
     "$eq": "df1qqal78l5uj8j86pq5ckchctgwxtn7uus5g53f8q"
    }
   },
   {
    "sub_transactions.address_to": {
     "$eq": "df1qqal78l5uj8j86pq5ckchctgwxtn7uus5g53f8q"
    }
   }
  ]
 },
 "direction": "forward",
 "docsExamined": 584877,
 "keysExamined": 0
}
```

I have created the following index

```
("sub_transactions.address_from", 1), ("sub_transactions.address_to", 1)
```

Would i need to create 2 individual indices?

Comment: [yep, you'll need two](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#-or-clauses-and-indexes)